# Gzip Compression in Angular with Weblogic

Tags: angular, spring, rest, spring-boot, angular-material

How to add compression like gzip for Rest Services (Spring Boot+Angular) and application server is Weblogic. There is many example appear which is for embedded server not for other like wildfly, weblogic. kindly help me to apply the same.

Answer (score 0):

By default gzip disabled in spring boot app, you need to enable and configure with below properties

```
# Enable response compression
server.compression.enabled=true

# The comma-separated list of mime types that should be compressed
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json

# Compress the response only if the response size is at least 1KB
server.compression.min-response-size=1024
```

> [WebLogic](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES532) Server 12.2.1 adds support for GZIP compression in the
>   WebLogic Web container, which you can enable at the domain or Web
>   application level